# How to test my app inside Free Developer Edition

Tags: page-layout, unit-test

Hi i am new to Salesforce and I have developed a custom app but i can't figure out how to test it inside developer edition.

I am using SalesForce Free Developer Edition. And in my custom app i have overridden default salesforce layout with a custom layout for 'New' action. Also i have Development Mode set to 'ON'. So when i want to create new records, salesforce takes me to custom layout. So everything is working fine.

But when i try to access same page through a test user salesforce shows `Insufficient Privileges` page, even though this test user have complete CRUD rights to this object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for the profile of test user add the visualforce page access

Comment: thanx. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like @mohith gave the correct answer in the comments but just in case anyone comes across this and wants to know how its accomplished.

**Setup -> Develop -> Pages**

Then you just need to locate the page you are looking for, and click security

[image]

You then just add all the profiles that you would to be able to access the VF page in question.

Comment: If any classes are "user facing", they will also need to be granted access explicitly on the profile (this generally applies only to global classes).

Comment: Good point.  Agreed.